# Corona: How to remove a timer from the exitScene function?

Tags: lua, game-engine, game-center, coronasdk

I need to remove the timer from the exitScene function as I remove all the listeners but I didn't found how. This is the code:

```
function scene:enterScene(event)

    planeta.enterFrame = rotarPlaneta
    Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", planeta)

    Runtime:addEventListener("touch", touchScreen)

    timer.performWithDelay( 1000, throwBrickEnemigo,0 )
end

function scene:exitScene(event)

    Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", planeta)
    Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", touchScreen)
    Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", planeta)

end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to assign a variable to the timer and cancel it.

```
local throwBrickTimer -- Reference for the timer

function scene:enterScene(event)

    planeta.enterFrame = rotarPlaneta
    Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", planeta)

    Runtime:addEventListener("touch", touchScreen)

    --> Give the timer a variable
    throwBrickTimer = timer.performWithDelay( 1000, throwBrickEnemigo,0 ) 
end

function scene:exitScene(event)

    --> Cancel the timer
    timer.cancel(throwBrickTimer)

    Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", planeta)
    Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", touchScreen)
    Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", planeta)

end
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but this timer "timer.performWithDelay( 1000, throwBrickEnemigo,0 )" isn't of "planeta". It's a timer which call the function "throwBrickEnemigo" each 1000ms @dburdan

Comment: @benLIVE If that's the case then you can put it in any other variable you like, so long that it is accessible by both functions. So create a variable called throwBrickTimer for example, and assign it outside and before the functions. I'll edit my comment to show you.

Comment: does this have garbage collction/memory issues where it keeps holding on to that timer object and isn't released?

Comment: Yes, @DavidT., keeping uncancelled timers can cause memory leaks.  It can also cause crashes as the Runtime tries to call methods on objects that no longer exist.